# ubBalance function in R

Tags: r

I am using the `ubBalance` function in R on a unbalanced dataset.

```
data<-ubBalance(X= input, Y=output,positive=1,type="ubSMOTE", percOver=400, percUnder=100, verbose=TRUE)
```

I am unable to balance my target variable. I get the following warning.

> Warning: No positive instances, skip balance

Please advice?

Answer (score 0):

Are your classes a factor? They should be numbers only (0,1) and also be a factor.

Comment: This would have been better as a comment as it seeks additional details and provides a mere suggestion but not an answer. Since you don't have enough reputation to write comments, consider contributing in other ways in the meantime, such as writing concrete answers to other questions and suggesting improvements to other questions/answers.